# Passar arquivo por parâmetro em uma função

Tags: javascript, html, json, xml, typescript

Estou fazendo uma função que transforma um arquivo .xml em um arquivo json... Eu achei algumas funções na internet já, que fazem isso mas eu nao sei como eu consigo passar o arquivo por parâmetro, como a função pede. Vou deixar o código abaixo para vcs terem mais noção.

```
function xmlToJson(xml) {

    // Create the return object
    var obj = {};

    if (xml.nodeType == 1) { // element
        // do attributes
        if (xml.attributes.length > 0) {
            obj["@attributes"] = {};
            for (var j = 0; j < xml.attributes.length; j++) {
                var attribute = xml.attributes.item(j);
                obj["@attributes"][attribute.nodeName] = attribute.nodeValue;
            }
        }
    } else if (xml.nodeType == 3) { // text
        obj = xml.nodeValue;
    }

    // do children
    // If just one text node inside
    if (xml.hasChildNodes() && xml.childNodes.length === 1 && xml.childNodes[0].nodeType === 3) {
        obj = xml.childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    }
    else if (xml.hasChildNodes()) {
        for (var i = 0; i < xml.childNodes.length; i++) {
            var item = xml.childNodes.item(i);
            var nodeName = item.nodeName;
            if (typeof (obj[nodeName]) == "undefined") {
                obj[nodeName] = xmlToJson(item);
            } else {
                if (typeof (obj[nodeName].push) == "undefined") {
                    var old = obj[nodeName];
                    obj[nodeName] = [];
                    obj[nodeName].push(old);
                }
                obj[nodeName].push(xmlToJson(item));
            }
        }
    }
    return obj;
}
```

E no html estou usando um onclick por enquanto:

```
<a onclick="xmlToJson()" class="menu">
    <div class="card menu-card">
        <div class="card-body">
            <center><h4 id="resultado"></h4></center>
        </div>
    </div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Vejamos...

Essa função de conversão para JSON funciona mas possui alguns problemas. Assim, vou considerar a [versão de Stefan Goessner](https://goessner.net/download/prj/jsonxml/), chamada de `xml2json`, com uma modificação que pode ser vista neste GitHub (*nota: link do github em breve*).

### Solucionando o problema

Para passar um arquivo como argumento a uma função, você precisa lê-lo de alguma forma. Existem algumas **formas de se fazer**: [*AJAX*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX) (com o `XMLHttpRequest`) **ou** por meio de *envio de arquivo do computador do usuário*. Irei abordar o segundo caso apenas pois AJAX é extensamente documentado.

**1** - **Para ler um arquivo**, precisamos do HTML correspondente para seleção do arquivo no computador do usuário:

```
<input type="file" id="arquivo" />
```

**2** - Precisamos também de uma **função de tratamento do arquivo XML aberto**. Esta função vai ler o arquivo e só converter em JSON quando o arquivo estiver completamente carregado:

```
function ler_arquivo( e ) {

    var arquivo = e.target.files[0]; if ( !arquivo ) return;

    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function( e ) {

        // 'conteudo' é uma string (texto puro)
        var conteudo = e.target.result;

        // transformamos a string em XML
        var xmlDOM = new DOMParser()
        .parseFromString( conteudo, 'text/xml' );

        // transforma o XML em JSON
        var meuJSON = xml2json( xmlDOM );

        // mostramos no console a versão JSON
        console.log( meuJSON ); // trocar pela sua função

    };

    reader.readAsText( arquivo );

}
```

**3** - Precisamos adicionar um **evento de escuta** para saber se o usuário fez a **escolha de algum arquivo**. Vamos então considerar também a hipótese do usuário trocar o arquivo:

```
document.getElementById('arquivo')
.addEventListener('change', ler_arquivo, false);
```

**4** - A **função de Goessner de XML para JSON modificada** pode ser encontrada no exemplo funcional fornecido (localizado mais abaixo). Estou evitando de colocá-la duas vezes pois é bem grande e vai atrapalhar a leitura.

**5** - Um **XML de exemplo** para teste. Salve em seu computador e abra no exemplo funcional abaixo.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<notas>

    <nota>
        <de>Burro</de>
        <para>Google</para>
        <assunto>Papai?</assunto>
        <mensagem>Não precisa de teste de DNA!</mensagem>
    </nota>

    <nota>
        <de>StackOverflow</de>
        <para>Brasil</para>
        <assunto>Versão PT</assunto>
        <mensagem>Já temos o SOpt!</mensagem>
    </nota>

</notas>
```

### Exemplo funcional

Abaixo temos um exemplo funcional que mostra o XML convertido em JSON. No caso, o resultado é mostrado no console.

```js
function xml2json(xml, tab) {
   var X = {
      toObj: function(xml) {
         var o = {};
         if (xml.nodeType==1) {   // element node ..
            if (xml.attributes.length)   // element with attributes  ..
               for (var i=0; i<xml.attributes.length; i++)
                  o["@"+xml.attributes[i].nodeName] = (xml.attributes[i].nodeValue||"").toString();
            if (xml.firstChild) { // element has child nodes ..
               var textChild=0, cdataChild=0, hasElementChild=false;
               for (var n=xml.firstChild; n; n=n.nextSibling) {
                  if (n.nodeType==1) hasElementChild = true;
                  else if (n.nodeType==3 && n.nodeValue.match(/[^ \f\n\r\t\v]/)) textChild++; // non-whitespace text
                  else if (n.nodeType==4) cdataChild++; // cdata section node
               }
               if (hasElementChild) {
                  if (textChild < 2 && cdataChild < 2) { // structured element with evtl. a single text or/and cdata node ..
                     X.removeWhite(xml);
                     for (var n=xml.firstChild; n; n=n.nextSibling) {
                        if (n.nodeType == 3)  // text node
                           o["#text"] = X.escape(n.nodeValue);
                        else if (n.nodeType == 4)  // cdata node
                           o["#cdata"] = X.escape(n.nodeValue);
                        else if (o[n.nodeName]) {  // multiple occurence of element ..
                           if (o[n.nodeName] instanceof Array)
                              o[n.nodeName][o[n.nodeName].length] = X.toObj(n);
                           else
                              o[n.nodeName] = [o[n.nodeName], X.toObj(n)];
                        }
                        else  // first occurence of element..
                           o[n.nodeName] = X.toObj(n);
                     }
                  }
                  else { // mixed content
                     if (!xml.attributes.length)
                        o = X.escape(X.innerXml(xml));
                     else
                        o["#text"] = X.escape(X.innerXml(xml));
                  }
               }
               else if (textChild) { // pure text
                  if (!xml.attributes.length)
                     o = X.escape(X.innerXml(xml));
                  else
                     o["#text"] = X.escape(X.innerXml(xml));
               }
               else if (cdataChild) { // cdata
                  if (cdataChild > 1)
                     o = X.escape(X.innerXml(xml));
                  else
                     for (var n=xml.firstChild; n; n=n.nextSibling)
                        o["#cdata"] = X.escape(n.nodeValue);
               }
            }
            if (!xml.attributes.length && !xml.firstChild) o = null;
         }
         else if (xml.nodeType==9) { // document.node
            o = X.toObj(xml.documentElement);
         }
         else
            alert("unhandled node type: " + xml.nodeType);
         return o;
      },
      toJson: function(o, name, ind) {
         var json = name ? ("\""+name+"\"") : "";
         if (o instanceof Array) {
            for (var i=0,n=o.length; i<n; i++)
               o[i] = X.toJson(o[i], "", ind+"\t");
            json += (name?":[":"[") + (o.length > 1 ? ("\n"+ind+"\t"+o.join(",\n"+ind+"\t")+"\n"+ind) : o.join("")) + "]";
         }
         else if (o == null)
            json += (name&&":") + "null";
         else if (typeof(o) == "object") {
            var arr = [];
            for (var m in o)
               arr[arr.length] = X.toJson(o[m], m, ind+"\t");
            json += (name?":{":"{") + (arr.length > 1 ? ("\n"+ind+"\t"+arr.join(",\n"+ind+"\t")+"\n"+ind) : arr.join("")) + "}";
         }
         else if (typeof(o) == "string")
            json += (name&&":") + "\"" + o.toString() + "\"";
         else
            json += (name&&":") + o.toString();
         return json;
      },
      innerXml: function(node) {
         var s = ""
         if ("innerHTML" in node)
            s = node.innerHTML;
         else {
            var asXml = function(n) {
               var s = "";
               if (n.nodeType == 1) {
                  s += "<" + n.nodeName;
                  for (var i=0; i<n.attributes.length;i++)
                     s += " " + n.attributes[i].nodeName + "=\"" + (n.attributes[i].nodeValue||"").toString() + "\"";
                  if (n.firstChild) {
                     s += ">";
                     for (var c=n.firstChild; c; c=c.nextSibling)
                        s += asXml(c);
                     s += "</"+n.nodeName+">";
                  }
                  else
                     s += "/>";
               }
               else if (n.nodeType == 3)
                  s += n.nodeValue;
               else if (n.nodeType == 4)
                  s += "<![CDATA[" + n.nodeValue + "]]>";
               return s;
            };
            for (var c=node.firstChild; c; c=c.nextSibling)
               s += asXml(c);
         }
         return s;
      },
      escape: function(txt) {
         return txt.replace(/[\\]/g, "\\\\")
                   .replace(/[\"]/g, '\\"')
                   .replace(/[\n]/g, '\\n')
                   .replace(/[\r]/g, '\\r');
      },
      removeWhite: function(e) {
         e.normalize();
         for (var n = e.firstChild; n; ) {
            if (n.nodeType == 3) {  // text node
               if (!n.nodeValue.match(/[^ \f\n\r\t\v]/)) { // pure whitespace text node
                  var nxt = n.nextSibling;
                  e.removeChild(n);
                  n = nxt;
               }
               else
                  n = n.nextSibling;
            }
            else if (n.nodeType == 1) {  // element node
               X.removeWhite(n);
               n = n.nextSibling;
            }
            else                      // any other node
               n = n.nextSibling;
         }
         return e;
      }
   };
   if (xml.nodeType == 9) // document node
      xml = xml.documentElement;
   var json = X.toJson(X.toObj(X.removeWhite(xml)), xml.nodeName, "\t");
   return "{\n" + (tab ? json.replace(/\t/g, tab) : json.replace(/\t|\n/g, "")) + "\n}";
   
}

function ler_arquivo( e ) {

    var arquivo = e.target.files[0]; if ( !arquivo ) return;

    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function( e ) {

        var conteudo = e.target.result;
        
        var xmlDOM = new DOMParser().parseFromString( conteudo, 'text/xml' );

        console.log( xml2json( xmlDOM ) );

    };

    reader.readAsText( arquivo );

}

document.getElementById('arquivo').addEventListener('change', ler_arquivo, false);
```

```html
<input type="file" id="arquivo" />
```